# Javascript error being pushed to the right by label

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

In the website I am working on there is a javascript pop-up (jquery) that appears if you enter an incorrect input into a text field. However, if there is a label to the left of that text field it gets pushed to the right.

Would anyone have some insight as to where this might be occurring, or what the cause is?

[image: Picture of what is happening]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/svTeU.png

Comment: we literally have nothing to work with but a picture here... could you post some code or a demo?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net works good for posting demos in your questions on SO.

Comment: or [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com) if jsfiddle is running slow :D

Comment: Random guess: your error has a margin-left equal to the width + padding of the label?

Comment: Second random guess: your input and label item are both individually floated, instead of being children of a shared container?

Comment: Thank you for the help, it would have a been a bit too much to try and upload an example of but the answer below pulled an occam's razor on me and after taking a look at it again i had simply missed the problem. edit: I just notice that Mike, your first comment also pulled the same thing on me. Thank you for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what is happening...[image]

So left margin is pushing the image out as the label extends down.  You could try floating it right and then having a right margin pushing it over instead.  It's hard to make a good suggestion without seeing the rest of it.

Comment: Thank you, I though I had cleared that issue out, but your comment made me take a second look at the css file and I do believe that it is the problem afterall. I will have to take a look at how I can try to fix this issue.

Comment: You try using absolute positioning on the warning if the multiple floats are causing you trouble.  Or, like I said, you could float the warning right.